# Flink s3 read error: Data read has a different length than the expected

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink

Using flink 1.7.0, but also seen on flink 1.8.0. We are getting frequent but somewhat random errors when reading gzipped objects from S3 through the flink .readFile source:

```
org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Data read has a different length than the expected: dataLength=9713156; expectedLength=9770429; includeSkipped=true; in.getClass()=class org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client$2; markedSupported=false; marked=0; resetSinceLastMarked=false; markCount=0; resetCount=0
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.util.LengthCheckInputStream.checkLength(LengthCheckInputStream.java:151)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.util.LengthCheckInputStream.read(LengthCheckInputStream.java:93)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:76)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.closeStream(S3AInputStream.java:529)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.close(S3AInputStream.java:490)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.hadoop.HadoopDataInputStream.close(HadoopDataInputStream.java:89)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.close(InflaterInputStream.java:227)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.close(GZIPInputStream.java:136)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.InputStreamFSInputWrapper.close(InputStreamFSInputWrapper.java:46)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.FileInputFormat.close(FileInputFormat.java:861)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.DelimitedInputFormat.close(DelimitedInputFormat.java:536)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.ContinuousFileReaderOperator$SplitReader.run(ContinuousFileReaderOperator.java:336)
```

ys 
Within a given job, we generally see many / most of the jobs read successfully, but there's pretty much always at least one failure (say out of 50 files).

It seems this error is actually originating from the AWS client, so perhaps flink has nothing to do with it, but I'm hopeful someone might have an insight as to how to make this work reliably.

When the error occurs, it ends up killing the source and canceling all the connected operators. I'm still new to flink, but I would think that this is something that could be recoverable from a previous snapshot? Should I expect that flink will retry reading the file when this kind of exception occurs?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to add more connection for s3a like

```
flink:
...
    config: |
      fs.s3a.connection.maximum: 320
```